# Error Code -201 when using ZKemKeeper.DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, biometrics

I am creating a C# WinForm using ZKemKeeper.DLL to fetch data from a Biometric Device. But when I try connecting my App to the Device it always gives Error Code -201

Any Idea what could be causing this? I've read a guide document for ZKemKeeper.DLL but it doesn't list -201 as an error code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IsConnected = TimeKeeper.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, 4370);
                if (IsConnected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeKeeper.GetLastError(ref ErrorCode);
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Not Found. Error Code : " + ErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

[image: Error Code When Connecting]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to telnet the device in port 4370?

Comment: also check the device is present on the given address.

Comment: Check the target cpu of your project, and try changing it to x86

Comment: @Zalomon & UmairAnwaar I can ping successfully the IP of the Device and also a standalone program can connect to the device with the same IP and Port used but on mine it can't, it only gives Error Code -201.

Comment: @Pikod will try, thanks!

Comment: @Pikod still gives Error Code -201

Comment: @Zalomon I tried using telnet on the device with port 4370 but it said connect failed. any idea why? thank you.

Comment: @Randolph did you find any solution? I am getting Error Code -7

Comment: i got Error Code -6 :(, any one have solution ? i have checked ip and port are correct

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                //ShowStatusBar(string.Empty, true);

            if (IsDeviceConnected)
            {
                IsDeviceConnected = false;
                //this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

                return;
            }

            string ipAddress = txtIPAddress.Text.Trim();
            string port = txtPort.Text.Trim();
            if (ipAddress == string.Empty || port == string.Empty)
                throw new Exception("The Device IP Address and Port is mandotory !!");

            int portNumber = 4370;
            if (!int.TryParse(port, out portNumber))
                throw new Exception("Not a valid port number");

            bool isValidIpA = UniversalStatic.ValidateIP(ipAddress);
            if (!isValidIpA)
                throw new Exception("The Device IP is invalid !!");

            isValidIpA = UniversalStatic.PingTheDevice(ipAddress);
            if (!isValidIpA)
                throw new Exception("The device at " + ipAddress + ":" + port + " did not respond!!");

            objZkeeper = new ZkemClient(RaiseDeviceEvent);
            IsDeviceConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net(ipAddress, portNumber);

            if (IsDeviceConnected)
            {
                string deviceInfo = manipulator.FetchDeviceInfo(objZkeeper, int.Parse(txtMachineNumber.Text.Trim()));
                //lblDeviceInfo.Text = deviceInfo;

                lblMessage.Text = deviceInfo + "is Connected";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw(ex);
        }
        //this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically download logs from the device into the software without having to manually click the download button?